# Use Perl to select multiple query output data from SQL database and place into single Excel sheet

Tags: database, oracle, perl

I am new to Perl so I'm hoping someone can help me with this,

I'm working on a special validation project where we extract data from database and show as an report in a excel. I have a Perl script to extract data from database and place into excel. But i tried to exact data from multiple query and to display the multiple output in a single excel sheet.

How do i return multiple query output in a single excel sheet?

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# connect to the db
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:dbname', 'dblogin', 'dbpassword');

my $sth1 = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(" select col1, col2 from table");

foreach my $ln (@$sth1) {
  my($col1, $col2) = @$ln;
  print "$col1 $col2\n";
}

my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'col1col2test.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$worksheet->write( "A1", "$col1" );
$worksheet->write( "A2", "$col2" );
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: use strict;
use DBI;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# connect to the db
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:dbname', 'dblogin', 'dbpassword');

 my $sth1 = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("
 select col1, col2 from table");

foreach my $ln (@$sth1) 
{ my($col1, $col2) = @$ln; print "$col1  $col2\n";}

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'col1col2test.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

$worksheet->write( "A1", "$col1" );
$worksheet->write( "A2", "$col2" );

Comment: @BalaRanga: Please don't dump code in a comment like that. As you can see, it's unreadable. It's a far better idea to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56322435/edit) to add the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is your code, then it will be throwing errors complaining about `$col1` and `$col2` needing an "explicit package name".

This means that you haven't declared the variables correctly. You declare variables using the keyword `my`. But `my` declares the variables within a block of code. So when you write this:

```
foreach my $ln (@$sth1) {
  my($col1, $col2) = @$ln;
  print "$col1 $col2\n";
}
```

the variables are only declared **within** that block. And when you try to use them outside the block:

```
$worksheet->write( "A1", "$col1" );
$worksheet->write( "A2", "$col2" );
```

You will get the error I mentioned above.

The fix for this is to declare the variables at the correct level - that is **outside** of the loop.

```
my ($col1, $col2);
foreach my $ln (@$sth1) {
  ($col1, $col2) = @$ln;
  print "$col1 $col2\n";
}
```

For future reference, when asking for help on a site like this it's really useful if you give us all the useful information - particularly any error messages that you see.